# how to dispose off objects that implement IDiposable and also the types of properties/methods invoked on them implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

Little confused (and not sure) with the kind of C# objects that I'm dealing with the at the moment.

For example:

```
   interface IMyInterface
   {
       IDictionary<string, ICustomPath> MyPathDictionary { get; }
   }
```

which is implemented by a class the also implements IDisposable

```
   class MyClass:IMyInterface,IDisposable
   {
   }

   IMyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
```

I know how to dispose off instance "myInterface" of object MyClass (either by a using statement or explicitly cast instance to IDisposable like

```
   ((IDisposable)myInterface).Dispose();
    or
    ((MyClass)myInterface).Dispose(); in the finally block after I'm done with what I'm doing.
```

But I have something like the following line of code

```
       IExampleInterface exampleInterface = some condition ? myInterface.MyPathDictionary[key]:myInterface.CreateSomething(key);
```

And MyPathDictionary[key] is a dictionary value (where the key is of type string) and value of type IExampleInterface which is implemented by another class called ExampleClass, which also implements IDisposable like.

```
   class ExampleClass:IExampleInterface,IDisposable
   {
   }
```

Now my confusion is caused by the above conditional statement since analysis of my code with a  proprietary tool says that myInterface.MyPathDictionary[key] is causing a leak of resources/memory. What I'm not sure of is that when I'm disposing off myInterface explicitly in the finally block of my C# code then shall I explicitly dispose off myInteface.MyPathDiciotnary[key] as well because if I already disposed off myInterface then an invocation of MyPathDictionary[key] on it (myInterface) should automatically be disposed off.

Any suggestions regarding this conundrum will be appreciated.

Comment: Hiding a disposable class behind an interface like that is pretty problematic.  The user of that interface will have no cue that he'll need to do the casting gymnastics to get the object disposed.  And won't, ever.  Any kind of static code analyzer is pretty likely to be thoroughly confused as well, it cannot connect the Dispose() call to the object.  You'll have to ignore that warning.  Help the client programmer fall in the pit of success by inheriting your interface from IDisposable.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the gymnastics thing but It's an old legacy C#  code where we created wrappers on COM objects and implemented IDisposable on classes rather than directly inheriting on the interfaces itself.And I'm supposed to change that legacy code anyway.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo in the last line of my comment above. What I mean is I'm not supposed to change the legacy code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyClass` owns these resources then `((IDisposable)myInterface).Dispose();` should dispose of them. It is a common pattern to have a disposable root object recursively call dispose on anything that it owns. That kills the entire object tree which is convenient and intuitive for callers.

The key question is whether the objects contained in **`MyPathDictionary`** are owned or not.

Your static analysis tool probably thinks that `myInterface.MyPathDictionary[key]` is a factory method that creates what it returns. Property get operations are method calls. To the tool this might look like a factory. This is a false positive.

On the other hand if you actually called `myInterface.CreateSomething(key)` then this probably did create something that must be disposed of. You need to ensure this. Either by always disposing `v` no matter where its value came from. Or, by differentiating between the two cases.

I'd just wrap **`v`** in `using` and be done with it. Makes it easy to review the code and conclude that it is correct.

Comment: The thing is that when I dispose off myInterface explicitly then I'm automatically disposing off myInterface.MyPathDictionary[key] (as you said) then why do I need to dispose off  'v'. Why not disposing off  myInterface will also dispose off anything created or returned by myInterface.CreateSomething(key). This is a little confusing for me.

Comment: The thing is that 'v' is of type IExampleInterface and IExampleInterface doesn't inherit IDisposable directly on it rather it's the ExameplClass that implements both IExampleInterface and IDisposable. So how come I can use a 'using' statement directly on 'v'. And if I need to use a 'using' statement what would the condtional statement look like in terms of it's syntax. Syntax apart how could I use a using statement on something which being an interface doesn't directly inherit IDisposable on it as mentioned earlier in this comment,

Comment: Disposal is explicit in the sense that the CLR does not keep track of object relationships and transitively disposes of everything. Your code must call Dispose on any object you want disposed. Is that clear?; You would not be able to use a using statement on v but you can use `using(v as IDisposable)` to make sure that in case v needs disposal it gets it.

Comment: using(v as IDisposable) =  some condition ? myInterface.MyPathDictionary[key]:myInterface.CreateSomething(key); Does this look ok to you?

Comment: That looks like invalid syntax to me :) `var v = ...; using (v as IDisposable) { rest. of code here }`.

Comment: But what would be the value of this expression var v = .....; I mean what do I need to initialize 'v' as ? Do you mean var v = the entire line of conditional code statement and then use 'using' statement for 'v' in rest of my code?

Comment: `v` just like you write it. It does not have to be typed as IDisposable because we do that with the cast in the using block. Is the approach clear to you now?

Comment: So what you mean is put v in using block like using(v){and then rest of the code}. Am I right? If not please do correct me .

Comment: I tried it and built my project but visual studio is complaining saying that "typed used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable". Where v is of type ExampleClass which is implementing IDisposable but still why I'm getting this error, no clue,

Comment: But in the actual code rather  than having var v= ...; we have IExampleInterface exampleInterface = ...; I guess compiler is not able to implicitly cast exampleInterface to either ((ExampleClass)exampleInterface).Dispose() or ((ExampleClass)exampleInterface).Dispose();

Comment: Please see the edits above where I changed var v to IExampleInterface exampleInterface.

Comment: What's wrong with `using (exampleInterface as IDisposable) { ... }` as proposed earlier?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I already did it and it worked.Thanks for all your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If implementations of your interface need to be disposable, the best way to handle it is to change your interface so that it also implements IDisposable.  That way its clear to all users of the interface that it needs to be disposed properly.  If some implementations don't actually need to dispose anything that's fine, they just have an empty implementation.

Comment: It's a legacy code which I'm not supposed to touch anyway.

Comment: @user2913184 Too bad, an easy fix would be to change the interface and add a base class which provides the implementation and have all existing classes subclass that.